# Using .not correctly JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit puzzled why my simple .not function is not working here.

```
    <section class='main'>
    <p class='tweets'></p>
      <div class='tweet'>
        <p class='time'>
        <p class='user'>
        <p class='message'>
```

If I run this .not code

```
$('.tweet').not($('.message')).hide();
```

Every child for tweet disappears. It's my understanding that when it runs I am asking it to look at my selector `class=tweet` and hide every child that does not fit the criteria of being `class=message` which should result in any elements for `class=message` being displayed on my HTML document and every other child being hidden in this case `class=time and class=user`. Is my understanding of this execution incorrect?

Comment: Yes it is. Honestly I am very new to HTML + jquery. I have no experience at all so it looks very amateur and I am sure I am not using the proper tags in the correct place

Comment: Sorry, they are not nested. I read the incorrectly. They have closing `</p>`. I just didn't include that part into the code

Comment: Use `$('.tweet > *:not(.message)').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) ***remove elements from the set of matched elements***. Since  *message* is the child element of *tweet*, your query fails to detect the element.

You should use `:not()` with [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

**Demo:**

```js
$('.tweet').find(':not(.message)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='main'>
  <p class='tweets'></p>
  <div class='tweet'>
    <p class='time'>10 AM</p>
    <p class='user'>user123</p>
    <p class='message'>message</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you but I don't understand why I have to use `.find` here. Should it not return the elements. According to the definition, "The not() method returns elements that do not match a certain criteria." 1. Why does my code not return the correct results and 2. Why do I need to use `.find` to create a new jquery object to return?

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis, `tweet` is the parent element in which you are looking for some child elements, so you have to use `find()` on the parent element:)

Comment: Does `.not()` NOT look for the child elements from the selector I give it at the start? I assumed it would or I am misunderstanding on how to use `.not()`

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis, `.not()` does not look for the child elements:)

Comment: Ah.. I see in that case then shouldn't this work? `$('p').not(($('.time'))).hide();` It is looking for all `<p>` tags that don't have `class=time` element. Yet, this does not work. Sorry, I just still don't get how .not works

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis `not()` does not take a jQuery object

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis, `$('p').not(($('.time'))).hide();` ....will select all *p* except the *p* having the class *time*:)

Comment: @Igor But in the example here at the very top: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_not.asp. They are clearly using a class as the criteria and a class is a jQuery object

Comment: @Mamun Yep, I expected that to work based on what you said but it doesn't. I'm not sure why. If that is the correct usage then perhaps something else is wrong in other parts of my code.

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis They are using selector string, not a jQuery object. But it actually works with jQuery object also, so I stand corrected, will add to answer.

Answer (score 1):

`.not` looks at the elements selected by the selector.

https://api.jquery.com/not/

```js
//$('.tweet *').not('.message').hide();
$('p').not(($('.time'))).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='main'>
  <p class='tweets'></p>
  <div class='tweet'>
    <p class='time'>10 AM</p>
    <p class='user'>user123</p>
    <p class='message'>message</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

or

```
$('.tweet').children().not('.message').hide();
```

or

```
$('.tweet > p').not('.message').hide();
```

or

```
$('.tweet > p').not($('.message')).hide();
```

or

```
$('.tweet > p').not($('.message')[0]).hide();
```

Comment: what does the `> p` mean in the selector part?

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis all `p`s that are immediate children of `.tweet`

Comment: why does this not work then? `$('p').not(($('.time'))).hide();` I don't see a point in selecting the parent `.tweet` when I can just choose the children `p` yet my line of code does not work. Nevermind! Figured it out. I have a parent `p` that does not fit my `.not` criteria hence hiding all the children as well

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis It works - see the snippet in the answer.